# What's the point of returning something from an Async/Await Function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I've created a code snippet here that fetches data about a certain country using REST Countries API. The function works fine, and returns a pending promise. That promise's fulfilled value will equal an object containing key value pairs for the country's capital, name, and code.

But if I wanted to use them for something, why wouldn't I just set that very same object equal to a variable and continue to program new actions inside my async function? Why bother trying to use values gained asynchronously on the global scope?

```
function getJSON(url, errorMSG = 'Something went wrong') {
  // feed it the fetch URL, then your customized error message
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(errorMSG);
    return response.json();
  });
}

async function countryData(nation) {
  try {
    const info = await getJSON(
      `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${nation}?fullText=true`,
      'Invalid country selected'
    );
    return {
      // Fullfilled value of promise
      capital: info[0].capital,
      name: info[0].name,
      code: info[0].cioc,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err); // display your custom error message
  }
}
console.log(countryData('Canada'));
```

Comment: _"But if I wanted to use them for something, why wouldn't I just set that very same object equal to a variable and continue to program new actions inside my async function?"_ Separation of concerns? The code responsible for fetching the data shouldn't care what will be done with the data. If it does then you'll have to rewrite data-fetching for everything, and end up with tons of code duplication.

Comment: _"why wouldn't I just [...] continue [...] inside my async function?"_ Because that would be messy in a large application, make it harder to maintain, and reduce your ability to reuse the same function in multiple places. If you don't see the point, it means that you have a very small application, and in this case, just do what makes you feel more comfortable

Comment: Modularity - that function should only have one goal and that is to safely retrieve the data.  Anything beyond that is outside the scope of what it's intended purpose should be.  As you develop more complex applications, you'll QUICKLY realize why it's so important to follow that philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` is an async function. Why do they resolve the promise to a response object, instead of continuing to run extra actions once they have it? Because they don't know what you want to do with it. It would be impossible for fetch to handle every possible thing that should happen next, so it just has a single job: get the data, then return it (in a promise). You can then combine this with whatever other code you like.

On a smaller scale, this may happen with `countryData` too. You might have 10 different parts of your app that want to do things with the result from `countryData`. It may not be "impossible" for `countryData` to implement all 10 things, but it's definitely impractical and not a good idea. Instead, `countryData` can be written to have one job: get the country data and return it. Then each of the 10 pieces of code can do their own things with the result.

This isn't about it being async, the same principles apply to synchronous code to. If you can keep code focused on a single task, without entangling it with the needs of other pieces of code, then your code becomes easier to maintain.